# How to get grandparent's column in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three associated tables: A, B, C.The following are the relationship,

A belongs to B , B has many A

B belongs to C , C has many B

I'd like to get the datas to_json in my A controller .

I had tried the following code

```rb
class AController < ApplicationController

def get_data
    @a_datas = A.all
    events = []
    @a_datas.each do |a_data|
      events << {:id => a_data.id, :title => "#{a_data.B.try(:b_id)}" , :start => "#{a_data.start_date}",:end => "#{a_data.end_date}" }
    end
    render :text => events.to_json
  end
```

The code can correctly output parent's id by

```rb
"#{a_data.B.try(:B_id)}"
```

While I want to get grandparent's id (C.id) by the same method

```rb
"#{a_data.B.C.try(:C_id)}"
```

I got the `` undefined method `C' for nil:NilClass `` error

How could I modify the code to get grandparent's id value?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying doesn't make sense. Your error message - `` undefined method `C' for nil:NilClass `` - is telling you that `a_data.B` is nil, so I'm not sure how the parent id code `a_data.B.try(:B_id)` could possibly be working?

But to answer your question, each `a_data` is an instance of the `A` class, and you're trying to call the parent class (`B`) on the instance when what you need is the parent association.

Assuming your associations are as you stated...

```rb
class A
  belongs_to :b
end

class B
  belongs_to :c
end
```

To access the a grandparent of an instance of `A`, you would do

```rb
    @a_datas.each do |a_data|
      events << {:id => a_data.id, :title => "#{a_data.b.try(:c_id)}" , :start => "#{a_data.start_date}",:end => "#{a_data.end_date}" }
    end
```

OR, if you're confident that `a_data.b` exists, you could do

```rb
    @a_datas.each do |a_data|
      events << {:id => a_data.id, :title => "#{a_data.b.c.try(:id)}" , :start => "#{a_data.start_date}",:end => "#{a_data.end_date}" }
    end
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I found that some of my data in table A do not belongs to any B. Therefore it works after I edit the code to become "#{a_data.b.c.try(:id) unless a_data.B.nil?}"